# How to test a function with a callback?

Tags: java, junit

Suppose we have an interface for a callback function as such:

```
public interface Callback
{
    void foo();
}
```

And we have a method that calls a callback that was given as an argument:

```
public void doSomething(final Callback callback)
{
    // Do something, like asynchronously fetch something from a server
    asyncStuff.doSomethingAsync(new AsyncResponseHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void asyncStuffDone()
        {
            // Call the callback
            callback.foo();
        }
    });
}
```

Now, to the question: Given this kind of scenario, how would one test that the callback indeed gets called?

Comment: Are you using a mocking framework, such as [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/)?

Comment: @MickMnemonic I do have Mockito available, although I haven't yet incorporated it in any way. I'm basically just learning around Junit and general unit testing at this point. If the question can be answered with Mockito, it's fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Supply a mock `Callback` object for the test and validate that the method was invoked.  For example, using Mockito as a mocking library, you would create a mock object (arrange):

```
Callback myMock = mock(Callback.class);
```

Then supply it to the code being tested (act):

```
someObject.doSomething(myMock);
```

And validate that the method was invoked (assert):

```
verify(myMock, times(1)).foo();
```

Comment: Thanks. I have two questions, though: Where do I call the `verify()` function? What if it takes a some time (10ms, 100ms, 1s...) for the asynchronous call to happen?

Comment: @manabreak: You'd call that in your unit test as part of the "assert" step.  As for asynchronous calls, there isn't anything asynchronous happening in the code in your question so it's not really clear what you mean.  The `verify()` line isn't going to execute until the `someObject.doSomething()` operation completes.

Comment: I may have been unclear with my example code up there. I basically meant that the callback would be called asynchronously.

Comment: @manabreak: Can you update the code in the question to demonstrate how that's structured?  Is there any way for the consuming code to await the result of the asynchronous operation?

Comment: I updated the code example. The only way I've figured out so far is to use `Thread.sleep()` in the test itself, which is sub-par. I've mocked the async stuff so it basically runs immediately, but my tests reveal that the test function is finished first before the callback is invoked.

Comment: You can use the `timeout()` function: `verify(myMock, timeout(100).times(1)).foo();`

Comment: I would suggest to not use concurrency in unit tests, as ideally they should be not dependent on it. You should check correctness without concurrency, or use synchronous implementation for tests. Anyway, you can use workingThread.join() to wait async action is complete to check Callback after.